# My laptop's suddenly stopped working.

Tags: motherboard, power

I got up to use my laptop this morning and there's a problem. When I try to turn it on, the light briefly turns on and then almost instantly turns off. I've tried to find some help and some other HP laptop user seem to be in a similar predicament. There are no beep codes, the screen doesn't turn on, not even the fan, literally just the light. I've tried swapping out sticks of ram, taking out battery and powering on with the charger only, taking out the charger and holding the power button (something to do with releasing static electricity). I don't know if maybe it's irreparable,  by myself.

I'm using a HP 6-1010ea, with an i5 processor and 4gb of ram preloaded.

Comment: Did you try with another power supply unit?

Comment: I don't have another charger, but I very much doubt it could be to do with the charger as when the battery is dead the light doesn't come on at all until you charge it.  It seems like it's trying to power up but somethings going wrong.

Comment: @Tobi - That indicates a problem with the charger.

Comment: I repeat.  It's not the charger, this morning the power light was orange it's now white signifying that the battery has gone above low.